# How to proof that $n$ dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ has n number of orthonormal basis vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Currently I’m studying linear algebra and encounter statement which says for 2 dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ there should be 2 orthonormal basis vector which is $\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$

I’m curious that is there a way to proof such statement, not only for 2 dimensional vector space but for any $n$ dimensional vector space $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, that $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ must contains n number of orthonormal basis vectors?

Comment: There is:  the Gram-Schmidt method allows an orthonormal basis to be constructed from any basis.  It can be applied to finite dimensional vector spaces or spaces with an infinite but countable basis. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process)

Comment: Which inner product do you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion arises from not having thoroughly thought through the definition of dimension. When it comes to dimension, the orthogonality or orthonormality of a basis does not matter. Any basis for an $n$-dimensional vector space contains exactly $n$ vectors. That is the definition of the dimension. The dimension of a vector space is the number of vectors in a basis for that vector space, which can be shown to be the same as

1. the largest possible number of linearly independent vectors in that vector space
2. the smallest possible number of vectors that span the vector space.